# floats confusion

Tags: css, css-float

Why is the orange box in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GBdDU/), not floating to the left with the rest of my boxes? I was for sure that the orange box was suppose to be taken out of the flow and float next to the blue box.  What am I missing?

```
  <div class=" wrap clear">
        <div class="block pink float"></div>
        <div class="block blue float"></div>
        <div class="block green"></div>
        <div class="block orange float"></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Can you post the CSS here?

Comment: @JanDvorak I tried to post css, but for some reason It was letting me format it correctly.

Comment: just copy and paste the css as is, then highlight it, then enter ctrl (or command) + k

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/GBdDU/1/)

`div` by default block other elements to be side by side but this behaviour can be changed by using CSS. If you want your orange box with blue one then you can change your arrangement. So, green div will not be able to push that orange one. Any div which will be placed after green one will be on next line.

Comment: But floating elements are block elements, too.

Comment: @JanDvorak what do you wanna say?

Comment: I just started learning html/css and just now found out about fiddle.

Comment: @AspiringAqib What Bolt says is true, but I've just found out is that a floated div does not sit on a line unlike a div that is still in the normal flow.  I used inline-block to fix the problem without re-arranging any elements.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you aren't floating the green box. So the green box is displaying block level and pushing down the orange box.

Comment: But floating elements are block elements, too, so all the boxes are displaying as blocks.

Answer (score 0):

Now replace to  your  html code as like this [**Live Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/GBdDU/4/)  --------- **[Full Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GBdDU/4/embedded/result/)**

```
 <div class=" wrap clear">
            <div class="block pink float"></div>
            <div class="block blue float"></div>

            <div class="block orange float"></div>

     <div class="block green"></div>
        </div>
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GBdDU/4/)**

Answer (score 0):

All block level elements sit on their own line and do not allow any other elements to sit to the left or right of them.  Although an element is floated and is considered block level, it has been removed from the normal page flow, no longer sitting on it's own line.  A quick solution to sit a block level element next to a floated element is to add the following css rule the desired element:

```
.Whatever {
    display: inline-block;
}
```